# pass variable number of arguments (both key & value) in PHP

Tags: php, variadic-functions

how can i pass variable number of argument(both key and values) to PHP

```
  <?php
   function tryfun() {
   echo "inside try()";
   $args = func_get_args();
   print_r($args);
   }
   tryfun(1,2);
   tryfun(array("key"=>"value"));
   ?>
```

output it get

```
        root@ip-:~# php trycmd.php
        inside try()Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
        inside try()Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => value
                )

        )
```

what i want it to be

```
        root@ip:~# php trycmd.php
        inside try()Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
        inside try()Array
        (
            [key] => value
        )
```

how can i achieve it in php
i am using Debian 7 wheezy
php 5.4

Comment: `func_get_args()` never yields an associative array.

Comment: What if you do `tryfun(array('key'=>'value'),array('foo'=>'bar'));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot dictate the "names" of arguments from outside a function.

```
function ($foo, $bar) ...
```

Here the *first positional argument* will be assigned to variable `$foo`, the second one to `$bar`.

```
function () {
    $args = func_get_args();
    ...
}
```

Here all positionally passed arguments will be assigned to an array `$args`. The values themselves have no "name", because "names" aren't passed.

If you pass an array with key-value pairs, as you do, then your argument is an array which contains key-value pairs. The array itself still plays according to the above rules.

Maybe you're looking for [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract), or maybe what you want is simply not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you : [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Create an array where you store all parameters, and give this array to call_user_func_array. It should work fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your input is an array:

```
$args = func_get_args();
if(is_array($args) && count($args) == 1 && is_array($args[0]))
{
    $args = $args[0];
}
print_r($args);
```

if you want you can check against other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function tryfun(){
    $args = array();
    $_args = func_get_args();
    foreach( $_args as $a ){
        if( is_array($a) ){
            $args = array_merge( $args, $a );
        }else{
            $args[] = $a;
        }
    }
    print_r($args);
}

tryfun(1,2);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

tryfun(array("key"=>"value"));
Array
(
    [key] => value
)

tryfun(1,2,array("key"=>"value"));
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [key] => value
)
```